# silverlight use Expander Toggle template on Toggle control

Tags: silverlight, expander, togglebutton

I like the look of the toggle button on the Expander control, when using a theme.

How could I apply this to a normal Toggle button?

Many Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to use Blend to make a copy of the default style. Oh wait, is the Expander still in the Toolkit? By which I mean, wasn't it migrated in the base library for Silverlight 4? At any rate, I think it originated in the toolkit, and the full source code for that is on codeplex, including the styles, so the easiest way would be to copy it from there. Also easy is to use Blend to create a copy of the default style and look inside it.

Comment: Expander still in the toolkit. I was just wondering if I could just apply that style without the edit copy palava. Gave my self an edit style headache yesterday, and couldn't handle any more.

Comment: I think I saw someone say that the button style itself is 'baked in' and cannot be reused as is outside the expander, but maybe that changed in 4; not really sure, but I'll try to look at it when I get to a computer with Blend 4 on it.